# Certificate issue for OPC UA Client in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, opc-ua

I'm pretty new to the OPC business but I have been trying to make an application using Unity that will act as an OPC UA Client and read some data from a server. Even though I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, using various sources I've managed to come up with the source code below.

I used NuGet on Visual Studio to download the necessary OPCFoundation.NetStandard files (Opc.Ua.Core, Opc.Ua.Configuration, Opc.Ua.Client, and Opc.Ua.SecurityCertificates) and put the DLL files into my Unity project.

When I run the code below, I get this following error:
`ServiceResultException: ApplicationCertificate cannot be found.`

I understand that I have to acquire a certificate from somewhere, but it is also my understanding that a certificate will be created at runtime? I can't quite grasp the concept of this, because when I look for the "StorePath" in the CertificateIdentifier, there isn't actually a folder on my computer called OPCFoundation. So it makes sense that it can't find the certificate, but I'm not quite sure how to get it.

Another question that I have is that, let's say this application was built and then given to another computer, would they need to have a certificate on their PC to run the program? This (hopefully last) bit has really stumped me and I'm not sure what I'm missing anymore.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Opc.Ua;
using Opc.Ua.Client;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class OPCUAReader : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Session session;

    async void Start()
    {
        var endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://opcuaserver.com:48010";
        var endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, new EndpointDescription
        {
            EndpointUrl = endpointUrl
        });

        var config = new ApplicationConfiguration
        {
            //ApplicationUri = "ApplicationTest",
            ApplicationName = "OPC UA Client Test",
            ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
            SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
            {
                ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier
                {
                    StoreType = CertificateStoreType.Directory,
                    StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault",
                    SubjectName = "OPC UA Client Test",
                    // Specify the certificate password if required
                    // CertificatePassword = "your_certificate_password"
                }
            }
        };

        session = await Session.Create(
            config,
            endpoint,
            true,
            "",
            60000,
            null,
            null);

        await ReadVariableValue();
    }

    async Task ReadVariableValue()
    {
        try
        {
            var readValue = await session.ReadValueAsync(new NodeId("ns=2;s=Demo.Static.Scalar.Double"));
            Debug.Log("Value: " + readValue.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error reading variable value: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```